# Default ajax call on command button press in primefaces?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have added few command button on xhtml page.All buttons are  but whenever i press this button then a ajax call is triggered even i have not written any ajax call code.Due to this my ajax loading image process does not work as expected.So please tell me why this happening?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what is the problem, and post some code? I didn't understand much from your post

Comment: When i press a button & i check in browser console then a network call is triggered.

Comment: Yes, that's what buttons do, it is normal/expected behavior. What is suppose to happen when you click it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can put

```
ajax="false"
```

on the Primefaces `commandButton`'s. The default behaviour is an ajax call.